# How do I build SEO friendly Ionic 5 website that can generate HTML and search engines can crawl that html

Tags: html, ionic-framework

We are developing a website in Ionic 5 - Angular. We want the website to be SEO friendly so that search engines can easily crawl the website. Normally if we do a view source of an Ionic project it does not show the full HTML content that is rendered to the browser and so search engines cannot crawl it. Is there any way to render Ionic 5 websites like normal websites?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for server-side rendering (SSR) which you can do with [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

BTW some search engines (Google for example) are already able to execute Javascript when indexing websites but server-side rendering might still make sense as it can also improve the site for normal users.